# PyGauge (wxPython Phoenyx) does not expand with Frame

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I wanted to add a couple or marks into a `wx.pyGauge` to indicate min, max custom limits.
This is the code:

```
import wx
from wx.lib.agw.pygauge import PyGauge as PG
#
#
class AFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.gauge = GaugeBar(self)
        p1 = wx.Panel(self)
        p2 = wx.Panel(self)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(p1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.gauge, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(p2, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

        self.Fit()
        self.SetSize((400, 100))


class GaugeBar(PG):
    def __init__(self, parent, size=(-1, 20)):
        self.range_width = 14
        self.limit_min, self.limit_max = (3, 8)
        #
        PG.__init__(self, parent, -1, self.range_width, size, style=wx.GA_HORIZONTAL)
        #
        self.SetBackgroundColour('yellow')
        self.SetForegroundColour('red')
        #
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.onPaint)
    #
    def onPaint(self, evt):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.Clear()
        PG.OnPaint(self, evt)
        #
        w, h = dc.GetSize()
        #
        xmin = self.limit_min * w / self.range_width
        xmax = self.limit_max * w / self.range_width
        #
        dc.DrawText('|', xmin, -8)
        dc.DrawText('|', xmin, 10)
        dc.DrawText('|', xmax, -8)
        dc.DrawText('|', xmax, 10)

#
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App()
    a_frame = AFrame(None)
    a_frame.gauge.SetValue(10)
    a_frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The gauge appears correctly with the two red marks and the blue gauge level.

However, when I extend horizontally the frame, neither the gauge level indicator or the red marks are refreshed to reflect the new proportions.

Interestingly, if I close and extend vertically the frame, it gets refreshed with the gauge and marks in the correct positions.

[image]

What I am doing wrong ? Is this a bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, by default, only the newly exposed areas of a window are painted on resizes and the rest is clipped out of the update region. So although your `onPaint` is being called, the existing parts of the window are excluded from the drawing region. The easiest way to avoid this is to use the `wx.FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE` style when creating the widget, however you may then need to deal with some extra flicker in some cases.

Comment: Thanks Robin. It did the job. While waiting for an answer, I made the application work using a `wx.EVT_SIZE` together with the `wx.EVT_PAINT` calling both events the same `OnPaint` function, then using a `wx.ClientDC` instead of a `wx.PaintDC` and locating the call `PyGauge.OnPaint(self, evt)` inside a `try/except` to get rid of the `AssertionError` which was received from the `PyGauge` class when calling from `EVT_SIZE` instead of `EVT_PAINT`. A bit convoluted. Now is more Phoenixtic.