# wxpython text inside a gauge progress bar

Tags: wxpython

I am building an GUI using WxPython, and was wondering if there is a way to put a text inside a gauge progress bar. 
This is in order to show users the battery status both with image and text.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47608498/pygauge-wxpython-phoenyx-does-not-expand-with-frame) you can find hints for a more general (customizable) method than that provided by the PyGauge class with SetDrawValue

Comment: Is it possible to put an image or text inside the gauge, e.g. when device connected to power source , display a charging image or write: "Charging" ?

Comment: Yes you are drawing to a [Device Context](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/dc_overview.html). In the example linked I draw text but you can also draw graphics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `agw.PyGauge`

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.pygauge as PG

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "PyGauge Demo", size=(200,100))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        gauge1 = PG.PyGauge(panel, -1, size=(100, 25), style=wx.GA_HORIZONTAL)
        gauge1.SetValue(80)
        gauge1.SetDrawValue(draw=True, drawPercent=True, font=None, colour=wx.BLACK, formatString=None)
        gauge1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        gauge1.SetBorderColor(wx.BLACK)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(gauge1, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, 20)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Layout()

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None)
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

For more descriptive text than a percentage, experiment with the `formatString` parameter and perhaps choose different background colours, dependent upon the percentage value.

Comment: hi, please tell me how to accept, your answer worked perfectly

Comment: @schantischul see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: Works for me after I change `wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL` to `wx.ALIGN_CENTER`. The original code gave me an error "Vertical alignment flags are ignored in vertical sizers". I'm guessing this is due to a change in wxPython since the original post.

Comment: @ArthurHebert-Ryan You are quite right Arthur the permitted alignment parameters have changed slightly. I have amended the code to reflect that. Thank you.