# Static/non-animated progress bar in wxPython

Tags: wxpython, progress-bar

I have a simple GUI written in wxPython and I'd like to display a static "progress bar" to represent the battery level of the device I have attached. I've tried using `wx.Gauge`, but unfortunately it has an animated glow (in Win10 at least) as you can see in these two screenshots:

[image] [image]

As you can see, not much going on:

```python
self.staticBar = wx.Gauge(self, range=10, size=(200,23), style=wx.GA_HORIZONTAL)
self.staticBar.SetValue(5)
```

I'm guessing that this animation is a feature of the Win10 UI, but is there any way to turn it off in wx? Or is there a different class I should be using? I've tried looking for multicolor ribbons/banners/etc (it's possible that I just don't know what the correct terminology is and that's hampering my search), and the closest thing I could find was a `StaticBox` which I hacked together with a `StaticText` to get this:

[image]

(minimal working example):

```python
import wx

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        subpanel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.staticBar = wx.StaticBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, label="", size=(200,35))
        self.staticBarFill = wx.StaticText(self.staticBar, wx.ID_ANY, label="", size=(100,19))
        self.staticBarFill.SetBackgroundColour("green")

        subSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        subSizer.Add(self.staticBarFill, 0, wx.TOP,11)
        subpanel.SetSizer(subSizer)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.staticBar, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(subpanel, 0, wx.LEFT,0)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class OuterFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, size=(300,200))
        self.Center() # center gui on screen

        MainPanel(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = OuterFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Which I am actually okay with except that I can't seem to change the size of the `StaticText`. I can call `SetSize` on the `StaticText` and it doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't do anything either (it's also not listed as a method in the documentation, so it probably isn't implemented?).

So basically, is there some sort of non-animated "progress bar" in wxPython? And if not, how can I cobble together something that resembles a progress bar/battery level indicator and is also able to be updated/resized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few options:
Note that the `StaticBox` doesn't show up on my display appearance `Theme`, bear that in mind. I've resorted to background colours to cope with it.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.pygauge as PG
from random import randrange

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None)
        self.level = 100
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour("gray")
        self.battery_level = wx.Slider(panel, -1, value=self.level, minValue=0, maxValue=100, size=(200, 50), style=wx.SL_LABELS)
        self.battery_level.Enable(False)

        self.staticBar = wx.StaticBox(panel, wx.ID_ANY, label="Battery life", size=(200,35))
        self.staticBarFill = wx.StaticText(self.staticBar, wx.ID_ANY, label="", size=(195,30))
        self.staticBar.SetBackgroundColour("lightgreen")
        self.staticBarFill.SetForegroundColour("darkgreen")
        self.staticBarFill.SetLabel("|"*self.level)

        self.gBar = wx.Gauge(panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=(200,35))
        self.gBar.SetValue(self.level)

        self.gText = wx.TextCtrl(panel, wx.ID_ANY, value="|"*self.level, size=(self.level*2,30))
        self.gText.SetBackgroundColour("lightgreen")
        self.gText.SetForegroundColour("darkgreen")

        self.pg = PG.PyGauge(panel, -1, size=(200, 35), style=wx.GA_HORIZONTAL)
        self.pg.SetValue(self.level)
        self.pg.SetDrawValue(draw=True, drawPercent=True, font=None, colour=wx.BLACK, formatString="Battery life")
        self.pg.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        self.pg.SetBorderColor(wx.BLACK)
        print(dir(self.pg))

        self.button = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Adjust")
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnAdjust)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.battery_level, 0, wx.ALL,10)
        sizer.Add(self.staticBar, 0, wx.ALL,10)
        sizer.Add(self.gBar, 0, wx.ALL,10)
        sizer.Add(self.gText, 0, wx.ALL,10)
        sizer.Add(self.pg, 0, wx.ALL,10)
        sizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.ALL,10)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show()

    def OnAdjust(self, event):
        self.level = randrange(1,100)
        self.battery_level.SetValue(self.level)
        self.staticBarFill.SetSize(self.level*2, 35)
        self.gBar.SetValue(self.level)
        self.gText.SetSize(self.level*2, 35)
        self.pg.SetValue(self.level)
        if self.level > 25:
            self.pg.SetBarColour("green")
        else:
            self.pg.SetBarColour("red")
        self.pg.SetDrawValue(draw=True, drawPercent=True, font=None, colour=wx.BLACK, formatString="Battery life "+str(self.level)+"%")
        self.Refresh()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Sadly, these options don't play nicely with the windows ui. However, it did give me some different ideas to try out for the display

Comment: @asdf Amusingly, I forgot my own previous answer. I knew there was another option, just couldn't think of it. I have added it just for forms sake.

Comment: I did find that pretty funny. It seems like you're the wxPython MVP around here

Comment: @asdf Seems you're forgetting `Mr` Robin Dunn and @VZ (Vadz)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the very nice answer by Rolf of Saxony, you may also check:

https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.agw.pygauge.PyGauge.html

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. Seems like this answer (by Rolf as well) is also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48006181

Comment: Accept my apologies for including, after the fact, the solution I gave in 2017, as noted by asdf above. ;) Take an up vote as recompense